# Java Optional containing an Array

Tags: java, arrays, option-type

In all the searching I did, I could not find an example of this sort. My bad :(

I have an Optional object containing an array. I now need to traverse the array and locate a particular element inside it.

Codes and sample classes as follows:

```
public class Component {
   private String name;

   public Component(String ipName) {
      this.name = ipName;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}

public class Container {
   private Component[] componentArray;

   public Container(Component[] ipComponentArray) {
      this.componentArray = ipComponentArray;
   }

   public Component[] getComponentArray() {
      return componentArray;
   }

   public void setComponentArray(Component[] componentArray) {
      this.componentArray = componentArray;
   }
}

public class TestClass {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Container newContainer = getNewContainer();
      System.out.println(checkIfComponentIsPresent("Two", newContainer)); //prints true
      System.out.println(checkIfComponentIsPresent("Five", newContainer)); //prints false
   }

   private static Container getNewContainer() {
      return new Container(new Component[] {new Component("One"), new Component("Two"), new Component("Three")});
   }

   private static boolean checkIfComponentIsPresent(String ipName, Container newContainer) {
      boolean isPresent = false;

      Optional<Component[]> componentArrayOptional = Optional.ofNullable(newContainer).map(Container::getComponentArray);
      if(componentArrayOptional.isPresent()) {
          Component[] componentArray = componentArrayOptional.get();
          if(componentArray != null && componentArray.length > 0) {
              for(Component component : componentArray) {
                  if(ipName.equals(component.getName())) {
                     isPresent = true;
                     break;
                  }
              }
          }
      }

      return isPresent;
   }
}
```

Can someone please advise me how can I improve the method `checkIfComponentIsPresent`? I want to know how can we traverse an array inside an Optional object, without converting it into a list or stream.

I can do it using streams as follows:

```
private static boolean checkIfComponentIsPresentUsingStreams(String ipName, Container newContainer) {
    boolean isPresent = false;

    Optional<Component[]> componentArrayOptional = Optional.ofNullable(newContainer).map(Container::getComponentArray);
    if(componentArrayOptional.isPresent()) {
        Stream<Component> componentArrayStream =  Arrays.stream(componentArrayOptional.get());
        isPresent = componentArrayStream.filter(component -> ipName.equals(component.getName())).findFirst().isPresent();
    }

    return isPresent;
}
```

But I cannot use streams, actually my classes are huge, and the array itself can contain numerous elements. Using streams, will degrade the performance.

Thanks!

Comment: `Using streams, will degrade the performance`, are you sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can operate with actual object value inside `map` method:

```
boolean isPresent = Optional.ofNullable(newContainer)
  .map(Container::getComponentArray)
  .map(arr -> {
    for (Component component : arr) {
      if (Objects.equals(component.getName(), ipName)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  })
  .orElse(false);
```

Actually I am sure what makes you think `Stream` would slow down your app significantly. And therefore there is another solution using streams:

```
boolean isPresent = Optional.ofNullable(newContainer)
  .map(Container::getComponentArray)
  .map(arr -> Stream.of(arr).anyMatch(component -> Objects.equals(ipName, component.getName())))
  .orElse(false);
```

Comment: Thanks @soon! But can you please advise me what is making it slower, as it really does make it. Is using `anyMatch` better over `filter` and `findFirst`

Comment: Without actual data (or at least data size) I cannot say anything valuable. Both `anyMatch` and `filter` + `findFirst` should behave in a similar way, since `filter` is lazy